# Download image to TableView [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, imagedownload

I have a swift project with the following files:

– **`ViewController.swift`** which mostly contains a tableView and in which data from Firebase is downloaded

– **`ViewControllerTableViewCell.swift`** which contains the outlets for the tableView

– **`DataModel.swift`** which contains the model for the Firebase data

In the table, I have included some labels which are filled with the data from Firebase, next to an imageView. The URL of the image is received in the **`ViewController.swift`**-file as **`authorAvatarUrl`** next to other strings from Firebase. After this process, the data is appended to a list (**`self.dataList.append(downloadeddata)`**) and the table is reloaded:

```
self.tableViewData.reloadData()
```

How can I download the image and display it in the imageView (which is inside a table cell)?

I have tried

```
// Declare variable
var cellViewController = ViewControllerTableViewCell()

[...]

// Download author's avatar
let avatarURL = URL(string: authorAvatarUrl as! String)
                Alamofire.request(avatarURL!).responseData { (response) in

                    if response.error == nil {

                        if let data = response.data {

                            self.cellViewController.profileImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)

                        }

                    }

                }
```

inside the **`ViewController.swift`**-file however, this is not working.

Comment: Use the simplest way is to use SDWebImage or Kingfisher

Comment: Do you have any errors? Did you try to add breakpoints and see how your code is executed?

Comment: It's a good idea to include your troubleshooting steps instead of just saying it isn't working. Have you stepped through your code and checked to see if the vars are being populated? Is there an error? is response.error == nil? is authorAvatarUrl a valid URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly the problem with your code may be that you are not referencing a `TableViewCell` which is currently displayed in the `TableView`, but rather a single cell you declared in the `ViewController` but never presented.

You should move the code to perform the network request in the `ViewControllerTableViewCell` class or in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method, and should reference to the given cell.

As others pointed out, there are many libraries who can help you with downloading the image's data and setting the `UIImageView`; since you are already using Alamofire you could use [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage).

Then the simplest way to download images will be to include this code in your `ViewController`

```swift
var allAvatarURLs: [URL] = // the array containing all the avatars' url

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let row = indexPath.row
    let url = allAvatarURLs[row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "<yourIdentifier>", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
    cell.profileImageView.image.af_setImage(withURL: url) // UIImageView extension in AlamofireImage
    return cell
}
```

Where `allAvatarURLs` holds all images' url.

Answer (score 1):

Use a library like [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

Then you simply use:

```
let url = URL(string: "url_of_your_image")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```